# How to use template strings in an api url for OpenWeather

Tags: javascript, api

im trying to use the coords that i get from the OpenWeather Api and change the url with them but i get an error and it says that i didnt declare the variable.

this is my code:

```
const lugar = document.querySelector(".lugar")
const tempe = document.querySelector(".tempe")

window.addEventListener("load",()=>{ 
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            long = position.coords.longitude;
            
            })
            
            fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=de0262f6f0eb8509b8337a940776247d&units=metric`)
            .then(function(respuesta) {return respuesta.json();})
            .then(data => {console.log(data);
                  const nuevaTemp= data.main.temp;
                  const nuevoLug= data.name;
                  tempe.textContent= nuevaTemp
                  lugar.textContent= nuevoLug});
 } })
```

Im a beginner so i hope someone can help me.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the URL in a variable then use this variable

```js
const lat = 10;
const long = 20;

const URL =`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=de0262f6f0eb8509b8337a940776247d&units=metric`;

console.log(URL);

/*
fetch(URL, {
...options
})
.then(...some function)

*/
```